# Converting chr "6/14/2017 15:00" to date and time in R

Tags: r, date, time

How to convert 6/14/2017 15:00 to date and time in R. 6/14/2017 15:00 is chr.

Comment: It is generally considered good manners to research before asking a question. Converting dates is a big topic in R and plenty of resources already online.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anytime("6/14/2017 15:00")
[1] "2017-06-14 15:00:00 CDT"
R>
```

Comment: I would be keen in learning why is this answer worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: Me too, actually.

Comment: You are of course free to answer and I didn't vote but I suspect someone doesn't like that you enable OP's extreme laziness.

Comment: And if someone wants to check, I am making _plentyful_ use of my direct 'close as duplicate' privileges...